# Ruby on Rails Has Many Through Array Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, has-many-through

I'm having problems adding to a **Has Many Through** association using `user_ids`.

My communication model looks like this:

```
class communication
 has_many :recipients
 has_many :users, :through => :recipients
end
```

In my create action for the communication controller I am trying to manually add `user_ids` to the communication object like so:

```
@communication = new Communications(params[:communication])
@communication.user_ids << id
logger.debug @communication.user_ids # is empty
```

I can't work out why `@communication.user_ids` array is empty, even when I do a hard coded id like so:

```
@communication = new Communications(params[:communication])
@communication.user_ids << 1
logger.debug @communication.user_ids # is still empty!
```

I'm still getting an empty `@communication.user_ids` array.

Am I missing something with my method? Any tips to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a `has_many :through`, maybe you need to supply full objects so that the relationship can be created smoothly.  Try this:

```
@communication = Communication.new params[:communication]
@communication.users << User.find( 1 )
@communication.user_ids  # should be [ 1 ]
```